# Restlet 2.0.11 increase number of threads

Tags: java, restlet-2.0

I am trying to run a server using restlet 2.0.11 but the server gives up due to too many threads.
Can somebody help me with increasing the number of threads for my server with an example?

```
try
{
    Server server = new Server(Protocol.HTTP, m_iPort, ContentProvider.class);
    server.start();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have search for a sample but the

```
getContext().getParameters().add("maxThreads", "512");
```

Gives me null pointer exception.

Comment: Which part of `getContext().getParameters().add("maxThreads", "512");` is null? Extract each part to a local variable and check for null.

Comment: Ok.  this works.  I needed to import org.restlet.Context;

Comment: Actually, after some more investigation, the getContext() returns null.

Comment: So, from what I'm looking at right now, you need to define the Context yourself: `Context.setCurrent(new Context());` Tell me if that works and I'll put it as an answer.

Comment: Yes, that's right.  I use this and it works.                                                Server server = new Server(Protocol.HTTP, m_iPort, ContentProvider.class);
server.setContext(new Context());
server.getContext().getParameters().add("maxThreads", "512");

Comment: Ok, so do you want me to put that in an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Eric's answer was probably correct for Restlet 2.0.11, but since this is still the top Google match for Restlet maxThreads, I thought I should post an update.

I don't know what version of Restlet/Jetty this changed in, but Restlet 2.3.7 no longer honors the maxThreads and minThreads settings. You must now call

```
server.getContext().getParameters().add("threadPool.maxThreads", "256");
```

As far as I can tell, this is probably a cosmetic refactor in the Jetty project by a contributor that likes to clean up code, without any regard to what users will experience when upgrading their libraries. Also, Jetty does not seem to warn you of invalid parameters at all. It just ignores them silently. That's exactly what you do not want to see for free-form String-String parameters.

Answer (score 0):

To set the `maxThreads` higher on an instance of a org.restlet.Server you grab the instance of the org.restlet.Server as its returned when you create it, then you grab its Context, grab the parameter list and assign a new property maxThreads with an integer, like this:

```
import org.restlet.Component;
import org.restlet.Server;
//...
Server server = mycomponent.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, "localhost", 9090);
server.getContext().getParameters().add("maxThreads", "512");
```

It looks like your mistake was you are grabbing the context properties of the Component, or the Java program itself, and naturally assigning parameters there will be ignored.

**Fuller example here:**

http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.restlet.data.Protocol

**Whole program in case link goes down:**

```
package carpool.serverMain;

import java.util.ArrayList; 

import org.json.JSONObject; 
import org.restlet.Component; 
import org.restlet.Server; 
import org.restlet.data.Protocol; 

import carpool.common.DebugLog; 
import carpool.configurations.CarpoolConfig; 
import carpool.configurations.EnumConfig.Gender; 
import carpool.dbservice.LocationDaoService; 
import carpool.factory.JSONFactory; 
import carpool.service.*; 



public class ServerMain { 

 //private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ServiceMain.class); 

 private static ServerMain me; 

 private Component component; 

 public void init(String[] arguments) { 

 } 

 /**
  * Start the Thread, accept incoming connections 
  *  
  * Use this entry point to start with embedded HTTP Server 
  *  
  * @throws Exception 
  */ 
 public void start() throws Exception { 
  component = new Component(); 

  // Add a new HTTP server listening on port 

  Server server = component.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, 8015); 
  server.getContext().getParameters().add("maxThreads", "256"); 

  // Attach the sample application 
  RoutingService routingService = new RoutingService(); 

  component.getDefaultHost().attach(routingService); 

  // Start the component. 
  //log.info("ready to start"); 
  DebugLog.d("ready to start"); 
  component.start(); 

 } 

 /**
  * Stops RESTlet application 
  */ 
// public void stop() { 
//  component.getDefaultHost().detach(component.getApplication()); 
// } 

 public static ServerMain getInstance() { 
  if (me == null) { 
   me = new ServerMain(); 
  } 

  return me; 
 } 



 public static void main(String... args) throws Exception { 
  CarpoolConfig.initConfig(); 
  DebugLog.initializeLogger(); 
  LocationDaoService.init(); 
  DebugLog.d("Excuting"); 
  // Load server logic 
  try { 
   ServerMain.getInstance().init(args); 
   ServerMain.getInstance().start(); 
  } catch (Exception e) { 
   //log.error("Failed to start server", e); 
  } 
  Thread thread = new CleanThreadService(); 
  thread.start(); 
 } 

}
```